# Inserting characters at specified position

Tags: c++, arrays, char, shift

I want to make a program that when the user enters `AB1245` and have the program change it to `AB 12345` (an added space between 2nd and 3rd character)

```
char Bilnr[9];

for (i = 8; i < 3; i--) {
    Bilnr[i++]=Bilnr[i];

}
```

As I understand this, this program will start with Bilnr[9] and set it to the value of Bilnr[8].

Then set Bilnr[8] to the value of Bilnr[7].

But it doesn't move any of the values. It simply prints `AB1245`.

Comment: Just use a `std::string`. It does the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: By the way, you're incrementing `I` in the loop body and decrementing it every iteration. It's never going to reach 2.

Comment: You probably want `Bilnr[I]=Bilnr[I-1];`. And, of course, we all know that "bilnr" means "car registration number". :-)

Comment: Thanks chris, I see that now. "duh" ;) Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I notice is that if your loop ever actually executes, it would be infinite

```
for (I=8; I<3; I--) {
    Bilnr[I++]=Bilnr[I];

}
```

`I++` doesn't mean `I+1` rather, it means `I = I+1`

but your loop won't execute, because your condition, `I<3` will be false from the get-go when you initialize `I` with `I=8`

You're also never setting `I[2]` to be a `' '`

you also also have to realize that arrays start at `0`, so `Bilnr[0]` == `'A'`

try

```
for(int i = 8; i > 2; i--)
{
    Bilnr[i] = Bilnr[i-1];
}
Bilnr[2] = ' ';
```

Comment: And fixing it solves the problem of which is evaluated first.

Comment: Is this even defined behavior, btw? This reminds me too much of the infamous `i = i++`

Comment: @lethal-guitar, Yeah, I held off because it was an intent to use `I + 1` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I seem to have thought the second parameter in the for-loop was: do until this is true, instead of: do as long as this is true. Among other mistakes. Hah! Thanks everybody, what a great community and website this is!

Answer (score 2):

This loop condition is wrong:

```
for (I=8; I<3; I--) {
    Bilnr[I++]=Bilnr[I];
}
```

`I` is never less than 3 so the loop never starts.  You probably wanted a `>`.  You would also have an infinite loop if it ever did start because you have `I++` and `I--`.

You want something like this:

```
for (I=7; I>1; I--) {
    Bilnr[I+1]=Bilnr[I];
}
```

Furthermore, you'll have to replace that location with a space, otherwise you'll end up with 'AB112345':

```
Bilnr[2] = ' ';
```

Comment: `Bilnr[9]` == `segmentation fault`

Comment: Thanks, I did have the space entry, but since my loop was faulty, I ended up with "AB 2345", got plenty of answers for the loop though, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It prints the same, because the loop never runs. The loop condition is wrong, it should be `I>3` to start. The [`for` loop](http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-for-loop-statement.aspx) works as follows:

```
for (initialization; condition-that-has-to-be-true; optional-increment-decrement) {
}
```

Also remember C/C++ arrays start counting at 0, not 1.

To fix your complete code:

```
char Bilnr[9] = "AB12345";

for (I=7; I>2; I--) {
    Bilnr[I]=Bilnr[I-1];
}
```

Then you have `AB112345`. All you need then is put in the space:

```
Bilnr[2] = ' ';
```

Comment: You are right. But it doesn't matter, you will have to put the space in anyway. I updated it, it just had to run one less cycle.

Comment: Thanks Bart, there were a ton of issues with my logic, got it worked out now!

Comment: Good. I just hope you didn't just copy, but also understand :). Good luck with learning programming!